# How to inject provider from another module in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this example not work? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afbT2/)
I get error what provider not found.

```
var m1 = angular.module('m1', [])
    .provider('test', function() {
        return {
            $get: function() {
                return 'Hello from provider';
            }
        }
     });

var m2 = angular.module('m2', ['m1'])
    .config(['test', function(test) {
        alert(test);
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `config` function you do not have access to it, try using the `run` method.

```
var m2 = angular.module('m2', ['m1'])
  .run(['test', function(test) {
    alert(test);
  }]);
```

What you DO have access to in the `config` function is the service-provider for `test` so you could do

```
var m2 = angular.module('m2', ['m1'])
  .config(['testProvider', function(test) {
    alert(test);
  }]);
```

This would typically be if you want to provide some sort of configuration to your test-service that would be specific for the m2 module.

Comment: Thanks! but ...why? I think there is a difference of service providers, allowing you to access the on configuration step

Comment: The configuration step of the lifecycle is there in case you want to provide any kind of configuration to a service before it is available for injection. It is briefly mention in the docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) with an example of configuring the hash-prefix for the $location service.

Comment: There's also an example here: https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232. If you wanted your service to say something like "hello from m2" you'd typically set that bit up in the config step.